# Azure Form Recognizer slow performance

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-form-recognizer

We are investigating the possibility of including document OCR into our product offering and would prefer to use Azure Form Recognizer. However, we are experiencing very slow performance when using custom or composed models for document OCR - often in excess of 10 seconds. Is this normal? If not, how can we improve performance. This is on an S0 tier on a local region and we are using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer v3.1.1 .NET client:

```
            string endpoint = @"https://123.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
        string licenseKey = "123";

        var credential = new AzureKeyCredential(licenseKey);
        FormRecognizerClient client = new FormRecognizerClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential);

        FormRecognizeResponse response = new FormRecognizeResponse()
        {
            ImageID = imageID,
            ImageTypeID = imageTypeID,
            ImageTypeName = imageTypeName
        };

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/ai.formrecognizer-readme

        //ID Documents sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer_3.1.1/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/samples/Sample11_RecognizeIdentityDocuments.md
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        
        if (imageToDetect != null && imageToDetect.Length > 0)
        {
            //Custom forms:
            var options = new RecognizeCustomFormsOptions()
            {

                IncludeFieldElements = false, //TODO: OK? We not using this in mapping,
                //Pages = {"1-3","5-6"} 
                //ContentType = FormContentType.Jpeg
            };
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageToDetect))
            {
                try
                {
                    RecognizeCustomFormsOperation operation = client.StartRecognizeCustomForms(modelID, stream, options);
                    Response<RecognizedFormCollection> operationResponse = operation.WaitForCompletionAsync().Result;
                    //RecognizedFormCollection forms = operationResponse.Value;
                    response = MapToModel(imageID, imageTypeID, imageTypeName, operationResponse, false); //Pass fields and reset in caller
                }
                catch (RequestFailedException rfEx)
                {
                    response.ErrorResponse = new FormRecognizeError()
                    {
                        code = rfEx.ErrorCode,
                        statusCode = rfEx.Status,
                        message = rfEx.Message
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {rfEx.ToString()}");                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response.ErrorResponse = new FormRecognizeError()
                    {
                        statusCode = 400, //(int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                        message = ex.Message
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.ToString()}");                        
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            if(response.RecognizedForms?.Count() > 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} Milliseconds --> DetectForm {imageTypeName} response: RecognizedForms:{response.RecognizedForms?.Count()}. Confidence: {response.RecognizedForms[0].TypeConfidence}  Error:{response.ErrorResponse?.message}");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} Milliseconds --> DetectForm {imageTypeName} response: No forms detected. Error:{response.ErrorResponse?.message}");

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            if (printDetail)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented));
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");

            //Error Logged in caller?
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: Empty image byte array");                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the normal performance if you don't train the Form Recognizer with samples you want to extract OCR information.

Comment: The models were trained using multiple samples of the same document type. Performance is slow whether I OCR a Passport using a Card ID trained model or OCR a Card ID using a Card ID trained model. Using combined models, performance is not significantly slower than using a specific custom model. This makes me think the engine is able to recognise the type of document relatively quickly, but then takes very long to extract the fields/data. Just guessing though.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention so that's what I've guessed.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to comment @Thiago. From your experience, is a 10 to 15sec response time expected for OCR of an identity document/card using a custom model trained on that same document?

Comment: it depends how many pages the document has. There are a few improvements coming, but that's more or less the same performance I'm getting at this moment. Let's wait and see if someone from MSFT will come and comment about this